# Flask + Celery: working outside of request context

Tags: python, flask, celery

today i started using Celery but am having an issue that am not able to resolve.
more specifically,

my Flask configuration is :

```
from celery import Celery
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(__name__, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task
    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery
app.config.update(CELERY_BROKER_URL="redis://127.0.0.1:6379", CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND="redis://127.0.0.1:6379", CELERY_IMPORTS=("netdiff"), CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 300, CELERY_REDIRECT_STDOUTS_LEVEL="DEBUG")
celery = make_celery(app)
```

I have 1 Celery task declared as :

```
@celery.task(name="implement_netdiff", bind=True)
def implement_netdiff(diff_):
```

I run a Celery worker as :

```
celery -A netdiff.celery worker
```

but, when i am calling the task :

```
diff_ = {'control': {'maintenance': maintenance,},'netelement': {'host': net element, 'ip': ip, 'pyez': None,},}
implement_netdiff.apply_async(args=(diff_,))
```

Celery complains about :

```
[2015-06-20 17:23:45,307: ERROR/MainProcess] Task implement_netdiff[714d5cee-b466-4075-9f8c-1b59b745e706] raised unexpected: TypeError('implement_netdiff() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 240, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/app/netdiff/netdiff.py", line 19, in __call__
    return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py", line 438, in __protected_call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: implement_netdiff() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

could you please advise on how this can be resolved ?

EDIT: i changed the declaration of the function to be "def implement_netdiff(self, diff_):" and it does not complaining anymore.

EDIT: "working outside of request context" was resolved like:

```
def implement_netdiff(self, diff_):
    with celery.app.app_context():
```

QUESTION: what `celery.start()` does ?

Comment: EDIT: i changed the declaration of the function to be "def implement_netdiff(self, diff_):" and it does not complaining anymore.

Answer (score 0):

This is [documented](https://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-request-info).

By specifying `bind=True` you ask celery to bind your method and get a task type instance as first "`self`" argument.

Comment: thanks @dhke, i noticed a bit later after writing the post. do you have any idea on how to resolve the outside of context complain from Flask ?

Comment: @NikosSkalis Not really no. Are you sure it is celery that is complaining? From what I gather that is a Flask error message.

Comment: yes, is true. Flask is complaining. i tried what is described in the Edit. but still no.

Answer (score 0):

Even after doing everything as documented, I was still receiving "outside context" error because I had not started celery with "sudo". So, that can be another solution to try, if someone is in a situation like me.

Answer (score -1):

`bind = True` is causing the problem. You can remove it.

Refer to the [documentation](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/tasks.html).

Comment: Duplication of another answer